# useEffect to trigger address verification based on filled out inputs

Tags: reactjs

I need to run the address verification api call .During these scenarios

```
   *when all associated fields are filled out.
   *when above call is done , it should be calling when any of the fields value has 
   changed.
```

I tried triggering giving all the fields as dependencies in the useEffects second parameter array,but its calls the effect repeatedly

```
const Address = props => {
const { countries, usStates, caStates, title, binding, formik } = props;

var zip = formik.values.Client.Address.Residential.Zip;
var city = formik.values.Client.Address.Residential.City;
var line1 = formik.values.Client.Address.Residential.Address1;
var country = formik.values.Client.Address.Residential.Country;
var state = formik.values.Client.Address.Residential.State;


useEffect(() => {
    if (zip && city && country && state && country) {
        console.log("call address verification")
    }

}, [zip, city, country, state, country])

return (
    <TransactConsumer>
        {({ userSave, getFormApi, formFunction, formStart }) => {

            return (
                <Fragment>
                    {title && <Grid item xs={12}>
                        <Typography variant="body1">{title}</Typography>
                    </Grid>}

                    <Grid item xs={12}>
                        <SectionField
                            title={title}
                            name={binding + ".Country"}
                            required
                            defaultValue={{ label: "United States", value: "US" }}
                            label="Country"
                            suggestions={countries}
                            component={MuiReactSelect}
                        />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12}>
                        <SectionField
                            title={title}
                            name={binding + ".Address1"}
                            required
                            label="Address Line 1"
                            fullWidth
                            component={TextField}
                        />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12}>
                        <SectionField
                            title={title}
                            name={binding + ".Address2"}
                            label="Address Line 2"
                            fullWidth
                            component={TextField}
                        />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                        <SectionField
                            title={title}
                            name={binding + ".City"}
                            required
                            label="City"
                            fullWidth
                            component={TextField}
                        />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
                        <SectionField
                            title={title}
                            name={binding + ".State"}
                            required
                            label={isUsCountry() ? "State" : isCaCountry() ? "Province" : "State / Province"}
                            fullWidth
                            component={ MuiReactSelect}
                        />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={2}>
                        <SectionField
                            title={title}
                            name={binding + ".Zip"}
                            required
                            label="Zip"
                            fullWidth
                            component={TextField}


                        />
                    </Grid>
                </Fragment >
            )
        }}
    </TransactConsumer>
)
}

   ====SectionField====
  import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
  import useSectionData from './useSectionData';
  import { Field } from 'formik';
  import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

  const SectionField = ({ children, title, name, ...rest }) => {
  const { addField } = useSectionData();

useEffect(() => {
    addField(title, name)
}, [title, name])

return (
    <Field name={name} {...rest}>
        {children}
    </Field>
)
}

SectionField.propTypes = {
title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
children: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.node), 
PropTypes.node]),
  };

  export default SectionField
```

Section Field component is wrapper for the formik Field Element.
   what would be the best way to make sure I can call only after all the 
   fields have been filled out . Right now , the it gets called for every 
   click , like lets say zip is 60000 it calls useEffect 10 times

what can be an other option rather than using formik values to 
 as dependencies.Any best practices could be helpful. Thanks .

Comment: It is calling useEffect multiple times because you are not using the cleanup approach that will prevent that. Use a `return` inside `useEffect()` and it will only run once: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1

Comment: I doubt if cleanup would work in this case , so its about how to notify the effect to run after  focusing out of the field . Even before I finish typing in the whole word it runs it . As  the If condition in the effect becomes true . So I am looking something that it checks for the field values and also if it has tabbed out .

Comment: UseEffect runs when component mounts. Think of it as replacement for componentDidMount timing in class components.

Comment: Is there a main ```Formik``` component in there? You could set ```validateOnChange```  to true, then hijack the built-in validation function to do whatever you need.

Comment: yes it is there. But validateOnChange is already by default set to true.

Comment: can u please show SectionField component?

Comment: @imk edited .Please check.

Comment: thanks. one more request. please show addField  of useSectionData . thanks in advance

Comment: Did you log type of and values of all fields in the effect just before `if (zip && city && country && state && country) {`? If they're all strings and nothing changed then the useEffect callback can only have been called if the component unmounted and mounted.

Comment: @HMR yes buddy I did log and double checked and all were string.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a variable you keep in state that indicates whether all of the fields have been filled out or not. You'd set that variable in the current `useEffect` that you have. It'd look something like this:

```
const [ allFieldsFilled, setAllFieldsFilled ] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    setAllFieldsFilled(zip && city && country && state && country) 
}, [zip, city, country, state, country])
```

Once you have an indication of whether the fields have all been filled out or not, you could have a second `useEffect` that'd be responsible for triggering the validation (you could maybe combine them into one, but I think separating them would make the intent a bit clearer):

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(allFieldsFilled){
       performValidation();
    }
}, [zip, city, country, state, country])
```

To keep yourself from having to type all the fields you want to be triggering the validation, you could do something like this:

```
const validationFields = [zip, city, country, state];
useEffect(()=>{
     //Code
}, [...validationFields])
```

Comment: I tried this ,actually when we type the last field of the validationFields array above ,  on  every key stoke ,useEffect gets triggered . In my case when I typed 5 digit zip,useEffect ran 10 times .  It should call only when all 5 digits of the zip are typed or tabbed out  .