# useEffect runs twice everytime

Tags: reactjs

useEffect triggers twice everytime , in-spite of provding the dependencies ,

when the 5 digit  zip is provided and all other fields are filled out , I see the console being logged twice, when it should have been called only once.

```
var zip = formik.values.Client.Address.Residential.Zip;
var city = formik.values.Client.Address.Residential.City;
var line1 = formik.values.Client.Address.Residential.Address1;
var country = formik.values.Client.Address.Residential.Country;
var state = formik.values.Client.Address.Residential.State; 

const validate = (zip) => {
    if (/(^\d{5}$)|(^\d{5}-\d{4}$)/.test(zip)) {
        return true
    }
    else {
        return false
    }
}

   useEffect(() => { 
        if (validate(zip)) {
            if (zip && city && state && country && line1) {
              console.log("Api call here")
            }
        }
    }, [zip, city, state, country, line1])
```

What am I missing in here ?

Comment: log the dependencies to check if one is changing

Comment: Can you supply a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: the dependencies arent changing , once all are typed for the first time , as per the condition set it should run only once. Later when we cahnge it will run again which is fine.  But I am not changing and  still unable to figure why its running the second time.

Comment: Unless you supply more information we cannot help you.  The code you posted looks OK.

Comment: @Brandon https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57909242/useeffect-to-trigger-address-verification-based-on-filled-out-inputs .